# mismatched types *string and string

Tags: api, go, github-api

I am attempting to run a conditional to basically see if the object is empty but I keep getting (similar variations) of this error:

```
invalid operation: release.Name == "" (mismatched types *string and string)
```

Here is the code that is dying:

```
import (
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)

func TestLatestTag(user, project string) {

    var client *github.Client
    client = github.NewClient(nil)

    releases, _, err := client.Repositories.ListTags(user, project, nil)
    var release github.RepositoryTag

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    } else {
        if release.Name == "" {
            fmt.Println("None")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(releases[0])
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the if statement to `*release.Name == ""` as the error suggests I get a different error, which I don't really understand:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x26fd]

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

I'm sure there is any easy way to do this but I am not very familiar with handling objects/structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code you have declared  var release github.RepositoryTag, but you have not initialized it.

In structure RepositoryTag, Name is declared as *string which is a pointer and in case  of release.Name == "", string comparison is attempted which is incorrect hence "mismatched types *string and string" error.

In case of *release.Name == "", since release is not yet initialized, it is complaining "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

You need to do two things, 1st initialize, release and second, check release.Name = nil.

Comment: it would be great to have an example, that would specially help any go language beginners

Answer (score 7):

From the error message it looks like you are trying to compare a `string pointer` (`*string`) to an actual `string`.

- `release.Name` is a `*string` (a pointer to a `string` value)
- `""` is a `string` (is a `string` value)

They are two different types. So you can't compare them.

What you probably want to do instead is `release.Name == nil`

When a pointer that **references** to nothing (equals to `nil`) is tried to be **dereferenced** you get that second error. So in your case `*release.Name` panics because infact `release.Name` is `nil`

Answer (score 3):

```
var release github.RepositoryTag
```

You never assign any value to that var. That's why `*release.Name` gives you a "runtime error": `release.Name` is a nil pointer